# How to use enviroment variables in Envoy

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, envoyproxy

How can I specify host and port data without writing it explicitly in the yaml file? I'd like to use environment variables, but so far all my attempts result in a json parser error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Option

You need to use envsubst, a tool that helps you put variables into envoy.yaml. You can do it this way

```
cat /tmpl/envoy.yaml.tmpl | envsubst \$ARG_1,\$ARG_2 > /etc/envoy.yaml
```

In the path tmpl/envoy.yaml.tmpl we save our temporary config where we prescribed where $ARG_1 and $ARG_2 will be used. Then we take these variables out of .env and rewrite $ARG_1 and $ARG_2 in the new config to their values.  So our final config that we can run will be in /etc/envoy.yaml.

If you would like to learn more about envsubst, I recommend reading the following articles:

- https://skofgar.ch/dev/2020/08/how-to-quickly-replace-environment-variables-in-a-file/
- https://www.baeldung.com/linux/envsubst-command

2 Option

Also you can use jinja2 + python to render your template.j2 files to yaml. You can find more useful information in Google or read this article:
[Generate yaml file with python and jinja2.](https://medium.com/@luongvinhthao/generate-yaml-file-with-python-and-jinja2-9474f4762b0d)